# How do I update the status bar from multiple viewmodels?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, viewmodel, status

I have MainWindow with a statusbar and multiple user controls in it. Each user control has a viewmodel. How do I bind/update the statusbar text from multiple viewmodels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple one that I have used myself.

Implement a [Messenger](http://geekswithblogs.net/lbugnion/archive/2009/09/27/mvvm-light-toolkit-messenger-v2-beta.aspx) system and give it a Singleton instance, say... StatusBarMessenger

MainWindow View-Model:

- Needs a string property, eg. Status.
- Needs to register to the StatusBarMessenger in the Ctor

```
StatusBarMessenger.Instance.Register(this, new Action(s => Status = s));
```

All VM that requires to send text to the status bar may do the following:

```
StatusBarMessenger.Instance.Send("Hello world");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PRISM then you can use its EventAggregator to Publish (from your user controls) messages and in StatusBar VM Subscribe to those messages.